# PHP/MySQL array help need

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$i=0;
$result15=mysql_query("select c.dishes from c");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result15))
{
if($row['dishes']!=NULL)
{
$dish[$i]=$row['dishes'];
$i++;
}

 }
  mysql_close();
  $j=0;
  while($j<=$i)
 {
echo $dish[$j];
$j++;
}
?>
```

Getting notice: Undefined offset: 2 in F:\xampp\htdocs....on line 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `while($j<$i)` there.

Remember, you incremented $i *after* the last insert. This means that $i will be higher than the maximum key of $dish.

Some thoughts:

Any time you're testing for equality with null, you should consider using `is_null` (or !is_null). It is more accurate.

This:

```
$dish[$i]=$row['dishes'];
$i++;
```

Would be better as:

```
// obviously instead of $i you would use count($dish) later (or use foreach)
$dish[]=$row['dishes'];
```

That final while loop would be better as a foreach:

```
foreach($dish as $val)
{
    echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the index exists before echoing it, as so:

```
 while($j<=$i)
 {
     if (isset($dish[$j])) echo $dish[$j];
     $j++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop is going to far. You only define dishes up to `i-1` and then you loop through it up to and including `i`. Change it to:

```
while($j<$i)
```